# Message not transmitted either to or from google cloud messaging

Tags: android, node.js

I am going through this tutorial [Android Chat Application using GCM](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/06/android-chat-application-using-gcm-server.html/2)  Basically you set up a node.js server on a machine and create a console.developers.google.com project with could messaging enabled.  I am running the app on two phones locally and everything with the node.js server seems to work fine: can log in, see other users logged in, move to the chat page. The problem seems to be when you click send, no messages are actually delivered to the other user. The part that seems to handle sending request is:

```
request(
    { method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization':'key=some-big-secret'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
  "registration_ids" : [to_id],
  "data" : {
    "msg":msg,
    "fromu":fromu,
    "name":fromn
  },
  "time_to_live": 108
})
    }
  , function (error, response, body) {

      callback({'response':"Success statement to gcm"});
    }
  )
```

which is in

> \node_modules\config\request.js

Nothing seems wrong in the terminal of the server, so I am at a loss as to why the gcm is either not receiving the message or transmitting it, the app has the real authorization key and project number as specified in the tutorial.